# SQL question, query is not updating account_id's fields: income, customerid, customergroup?

Tags: sql

I am executing this query through a databricks notebook, to join data from a stage table to a target table based on the shared join keys: account_id and stmt_end_dt. The stage table has 2 billion rows of data and the target table has 3 billion rows of data.

Here is the main query:

```
"UPDATE TARGET_TBL SET INCOME = S.INCOME, CUSTOMERGROUPID = S.CUSTOMERGROUPID, CUSTOMERID = S.CUSTOMERID
FROM STAGE_TBL AS S
WHERE CAST(S.ACCT_ID AS NUMBER(18,0)) = TARGET_TBL.ACCT_ID
AND CAST(S.STMT_END_DT AS DATE) = TARGET_TBL.STMT_END_DT"
```

What I want to do is add "income", "customerid", and "customergroup" data to the matching rows of "account_id" and "stmt_end_dt" in the target table, from the stage table. When I go into the target table I see that there are now fields for "income", "customerid", and "customergrop" (this is fine because it was created through an earlier query). After my query has run and I click into the target table I see that account_id is **blank** and that "income", "customerid" and "customergroup" all have data filled. And when I run this query: `SELECT * FROM TARGET_TBL WHERE INCOME IS NOT NULL`; I get back 80000 rows (seems kinda low considering the stage table is 2 billion). Also after that query runs I see again that "income", "customerid" and "customergroup" are all populated with data, but account_id is full of NULLS. It is as this data is just being appended or tacked on, and not updating each account_id's fields with the matching data, this is how I imagine it should look like:

```
account_id | income | customerid | customergroupid 
4321       | 60000  | 6345       | 3
5432       | 55000  | 4345       | 5
```

But instead it looks like this:

```
account_id | income | customerid | customergroupid 
           | 60000  | 6345       | 3
           | 55000  | 4345       | 5
```

Or when I run: SELECT * WHERE INCOME IS NOT NULL:

```
account_id | income | customerid | customergroupid 
NULL       | 60000  | 6345       | 3
NULL       | 55000  | 4345       | 5
```

And if I simply open the target table it looks like this:

```
account_id | income | customerid | customergroupid 
4321       |        |            | 
5432       |        |            |
```

After that query runs, it is also NULL for all other fields outside of the last 3 shown.

Perhaps the data types coming from the stage table aren't compatible with the target table?

What could be causing this strange behavior?

Answer (score 0):

you can't compare "values" with "null"... if a field is "null" there is nothing to compare. I believe this is your problem.

if you have null fields and you want to compare, usually you can try "is null" or "nvl" lookup for the syntax of these.. it is very helpfull.

Comment: Thanks. So how would the SQL query be changed?